# nav-toggle not showing its invisible reactjs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

i am new to react. for making page responsive i have added nav-toggle for header. but its not showing anything. while inspecting its there but invisible.and while clicking it the page is refreshing.code is given below.

code:-

```
    <section id="home" role="banner">
    <header id="header">
        <div className="header-content clearfix">
            <a href=""><img src={logo} alt="" className="logo" /></a>
            <nav className="navigation">
                <ul className="primary-nav">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#card">Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cata">Categories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#test">Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#test2">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#busns" className="btn btnadd">Adds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/login">LOGIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a href="" className="nav-toggle" data-target="#navigation">Menu<span></span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
</section>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create fiddle of that?

Comment: replace class with className. You need to use className in place of class in react for css styles

Comment: ok, let me try it

Comment: i have changed class into className but still the same , page is refreshing nothing else

Comment: Do you have bootstrap css added in your index.html?

Comment: no sir i am using reactstrap

Comment: Okey have you added this in index.html <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/6.0.1/reactstrap.min.js"></script>  ??? as suggested in this doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactstrap

Comment: sorry for the delay. i have added that script to the index.html but its still the same issue happening

Comment: can you clarify if you are running reactstrap from cdn or using a bundle (such as cra)?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have all the required dependencies installed and setup correctly. (See [reacstrap documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/)).

See [reactstrap-navbartoggler-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-navbartoggler-example?file=Example.js) for a complete working example.

This is an example component to implement the navbar:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
} from 'reactstrap';

const links = [
  { href: '#home', text: 'Home' },
  { href: '#card', text: 'Product' },
  { href: '#about', text: 'About' },
  { href: '#cata', text: 'Categories' },
  { href: '#test', text: 'Blogs' },
  { href: '#test2', text: 'News' },
  { href: '#busns', text: 'Adds', className: 'btnadd' },
  { href: '/login', text: 'LOGIN' },
];

const createNavItem = ({ href, text, className }) => (
  <NavItem>
    <NavLink href={href} className={className}>{text}</NavLink>
  </NavItem>
);

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              {links.map(createNavItem)}
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**A word of caution:** in the Reacstrap docs, there is a link to a demo under Installation/CDN. That demo is VERY old (reacstrap v2 and react v15). The dependencies from the demo will not work with some of the examples in the components section of the Reacstrap docs (including the icon for the collapse button).